# Why is boot returning all NA values

Tags: r, mean, difference, resampling

Can anyone tell me why `boot()` is returning all NA values in the code below please?

```
library(boot)

diff.means.boot <- function(data, k) {

    m1 <- mean(subset(data, vs == 1)[k, "mpg"])
    m2 <- mean(subset(data, vs == 0)[k, "mpg"])

    return(m1-m2)

}

boot(data=mtcars, statistic=diff.means.boot, R=1000)
```

Comment: The length of k will not be the same as the number of rows in the subsets.

Comment: What will be the length of k?

Comment: It it's an ordinary bootstrap wouldn't it be the same as the number of rows of the data argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally unwise to use `subset` within functions, but even more unwise to index with a vector that is of a different length than the number of rows of the data-object.

The `boot` function passes a series of index vectors of row-names that have been sampled with replacement from the "universe" (sampling-frame) of the full dataset.  Instead, use the "[" function for your additional level of sub-setting *after* the indexing is complete:

```
diff.means.boot <- function(data, k) {

    m1 <- mean(data[k, ][data$vs==1, "mpg"])
    m2 <- mean(data[k, ][data$vs==0, "mpg"])

    return(m1-m2)
}
```

After the same call:

```
# Bootstrap Statistics :
#     original    bias    std. error
# t1* 7.940476 -7.837067    2.079209
```